# How to access the different struct variable using other struct variable?

Tags: go

I have two structs and one containing one field and other contains three fields:-

```
type User struct {
  Name []CustomerDetails `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}
type CustomerDetails struct {
  Value             string `json:"value" bson:"value"`
  Note              string `json:"note" bson:"note"`
  SendNotifications bool   `json:"send_notifications" bson:"send_notifications"`
}
```

I want to access the `CustomerDetails` fields using the `User` struct field like

```
func main() {
  var custName User
  custName.Name.Value = "ABC"
  fmt.Println(custName)
}
```

But It gives me the error of

> custName.Name.Value undefined (type []CustomerDetails has no field or method Value)

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Hf5VoDsu1xR)

How will I solve this error? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Because `Name` is a slice. You should use respective indexes to set the value on them. If there will be only one CustomerDetail for each user, then replace `[]CustomerDetails` to `CustomerDetails`.

Comment: @Berkant I Can't change it like you say. Is there is another method without changing the struct?

Comment: You may try appending to `custName.Name`. https://play.golang.org/p/PB9y5svCWwT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type User struct {
  Name []CustomerDetails `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}
```

Here, `User.Name` is slice, that's why you are getting error.

```
func main() {
  var custName User
  custName.Name = append(custName.Name, CustomerDetails{
    Value: "ABC",
  })
  fmt.Println(custName)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/J56LjH7Lqdd

Answer (score 0):

You should append the `CustomerDetails` to `User.Name` like so: https://play.golang.org/p/jk73roZiAC2

```
var custName User

cd := CustomerDetails{
        Value: "ABC",
        Note: "Test",
    }

custName.Name = append(custName.Name, cd)

fmt.Println(custName)
```

`User.Name` is a slice so you can't give it a single value.